# Using a variable in component URL in laravel markdown mail

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have the following markdown mail in Laravel:

```
# Welcome to Offer Site
Thanks for listing your product, {{$user->name}}! 

@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'https://www.example.com/product/view/{{$product->id}}', 'color'=> 'orange'])
View it here
@endcomponent
```

However, the rendered URL when the mail is sent is `https://www.example.com/product/view/%3C?php%20echo%20e(%24product-%3Eid);%20?%3E`

This is probably super simple but its hard to word... how do I go about making sure the variable is properly inserted into the URL bar as the parameter, this is in the build of the `ProductAdded` mail:

```
return $this->markdown('emails.product-added-email');
```

And this is what I pass to `ProductAdded` Mail:

`\Mail::to($user)->send(new \App\Mail\ProductAdded($user, $product));`

The variables work fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are already inside a php string, there is no need to use the blade brackets. You can just concatenate the string like so:

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'https://www.example.com/product/view/' . $product->id, 'color' => 'orange'])
```

Comment: Ah that was it, sorry I knew it would've been something like this. Appreciate your help Jerodev! (ill tick when SO lets me)