# How to create an url correctly with laravel blade and component?

Tags: php, laravel-5, components

I can't format an url correctly with laravel blade and component.

I have tried this.

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'http://blog.test/activation/{{$user->activations()->token}}'])
```

This give me

```
 blog.test/activation/<?php echo e($user->activations()->token);?>
```

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570175/using-a-variable-in-component-url-in-laravel-markdown-mail

Comment: Oh,, I missed that one. Thanks!